# Set DevExpress SpinEdit value via jquery

Tags: jquery, devexpress-mvc

I have three DevExpress SpinEdit fields and I want to set the values of these fields via jquery.

```
$('#calculator_gross').click(function () {
    $('#Gross_I').val(parseFloat($('#Net_I').val()) + parseFloat($('#Tare_I').val()));
});
```

It sets the value of the field ([see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK3Lx.png))

But when I click on field it sets back to the value before ([see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVRXs.png))

Answer (score 0):

Test using javascript, I've done it like this, I hope it works.

```
SpinEdit.SetValue(parseInt("123"));
```